# Изучение AWT

Tags: awt, java

Есть ли смысл (практический, в первую очередь) в изучении AWT? Иначе: насколько востребованы в настоящее время знание его и навыки работы?

Answer (score 3):

AWT не кроссплатформенна, да и не универсальна. Юзайте Swing. Для изучения идеальна книга Г.Шилдт "Swing".
Успехов :)

Comment: Да мне тоже понравилась эта книга...

Comment: Почему не кроссплатформена? Я пробовал, идет и в лине, и в винде.

Comment: Насколько я знаю - кроссплатформенная.

Просто начните учить **swing** во всех книгах 100%, так или иначе, будет рассмотрена AWT и почему это плохо :)

Comment: Ну, то что она выглядит хуже ядерной войны, это ясно. Кстати, проверил, еще и на OpenSolaris вполне даже идет.

Comment: Там проблем намного больше. Просто начните читать и вы все поймете. Уже если серьезно и swing( по неизвестным мне причинам  ) считается dipricated... Что уж говорить о AWT :)

Вообще - в процессе изучения книг вы, если будете все честно читать и во все честно вникать ;) - изучите и awt

Comment: Еще есть графическая библиотека SWT от EclipseIDE. Она полегче, чем Swing будет. Рекомендую погуглить по этой теме =)

Comment: А вы не знаете примеров софта реализованного с использованием SWT?

Comment: Не могу сказать. Знаю то, что это есть.Даже пробовал работать. Знаете, мне понравилось. Работает без нареканий и там можно поиграться с разными настройками компонентов.

Answer (score 1):

Естественно смысл есть т.к. **swing** пошла после awt, но глубоко вникать нет необходимости.

Вообщем ИМХО для самообразования и лучшего понимания нужно пробежаться, зацикливаться на ней 100% не стоит

Answer (score 1):

AWT напрямую вызвает более низкоуровневую нативную подпрограмму, которая и создает компоненты. Другими словами, GUI программа, написанная с использованием AWT, выглядит как родное приложение Microsoft Windows, будучи запущенной на Windows, и в то же время как родное приложение Apple Macintosh, будучи запущенным на Mac, и т. д.. Однако, некоторым разработчикам не нравится эта модель, потому что они предпочитают, чтобы их приложения выглядели одинаково на всех платформах.
Swing обеспечивает возможность использования либо системного «look and feel», который использует родной «look and feel» платформы, либо кросс-платформенный внешний вид («Java Look and Feel»), который выглядят одинаково на всех платформах. Тем не менее, Swing использует AWT для взаимодействия с родной оконной системой.  
Рекомендую прочитать первую главу [этой](http://academicasu.googlecode.com/files/swingbook.pdf) книги и вы всё поймёте, займёт мин 30 -1ч, написано довольно интересно! ;)